# Check Box Disablement On Page Reload Jscript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I select the boxes, I want the text fields to become editable. At first it works but if I reload the page with the boxes checked, it will do the opposite of what it is supposed to do (i.e. after page is reloaded, when the boxes aren't checked, the text fields are editable; when checked, they become un-editable)

```
<table>
<tr>    
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Download_Limit" value="download" class="checkme"/>Download Limit
        <br/>   
        <input type="text" name="download" class="text required" id="Download_Input" size="3">
        <label class="description" for="Expire">Downloads</label>   
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>    
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Time_Limit" value="time"  class="checkme"/>Time Limit
        <br/>
        <input type="text" name="time" class="text required" id="Time_Input" size="3">
        <label class="description" for="Expire">Hours</label>
    </td>
</tr>
```

My Javascript

```
$('.checkme').attr('checked', false);
$('.checkme').click(function(){
    if($('input[name='+ $(this).attr('value')+']').attr('disabled') == false){
        $('input[name='+ $(this).attr('value')+']').attr('disabled', true);
    }else{
        $('input[name='+ $(this).attr('value')+']').attr('disabled', false);
    }
 });
```

Comment: _"but if I reload the page with the boxes checked"_ How do you do that? Are you storing the checkbox state somehow?

Comment: I do not think I am  storing the boxes' state, I just have it checked and then if I press F5 then it will do what is stated above.

Comment: @j08691 IE and FF don't reset the input values after refresh.

Comment: @Teemu - not something you should rely on.

Comment: @Teemu So how would I go about refreshing the values? And thank you for that piece of information.

Comment: Whatever happens, don't forget to close the table ;)

Comment: @user3010773 Use a `form` and [reset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement.reset) it before the page unloads?

Comment: @user3010773 Please check out my example below. It's very simplified. Let me know if that does it for you. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/OdoQiXEC/1/edit)** . I think it's more elegant.

```
$('.checkme').click(function() {
  var input = $(this).closest('td').find('input[type="text"]');
  if (input.is(':disabled')){ 
  input.attr('disabled', false);
  }else{
   input.attr('disabled', true);
  }
});
```

Also, your input type="text" mark up should be disabled as follows:

```
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" name="time" class="text required" id="Time_Input" size="3" />
```

Comment: Your script works, but opposite when applied to my site. I am not sure why

Comment: Look at the html markup. Your input type="text" should be disabled by default. I.E. input type="text" disabled="disabled"

Comment: I have modified my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I would do. First, setup all the default values that you want:

```
// Set default page values on load...
$('.checkme').prop('checked', false);
$('input[type="text"]').prop('disabled', true).val('');

// Then setup events...
$('.checkme').on('click', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if($('input[name='+ $this.val() +']').prop('disabled')){
        $('input[name='+ $this.val()+']').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
        $('input[name='+ $this.val()+']').prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

We've changed a few things up here. Let me explain.

1. First, we've changed `.attr('checked'...)` and `.attr('disabled'...)` to use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead. ***checked*** and ***disabled*** are properties not attributes.
2. We're now attaching the event using [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/). This is just the method I prefer, however simply doing `.click()` will work as well.
3. We're saving off the element into a local variable `$this` first thing. This keeps jQuery from having to re-traverse the DOM multiple times within the same function.
4. I've simplified `.attr('value')` to the shorthand `.val()`.
5. Lastly, we've simplified your `if` statement by removing the negative condition and allowing JavaScript to use the ***truthy/falsy*** conditionals.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/warlock5658/yjR48/)

**A Few Other Notes:**

I know it is a traditional method of page layout, but I highly discourage using tables to position elements. It is not the appropriate use of tables and results in a page layout that is not semantically correct. Check out the `<div>` and `<span>` elements to layout your code and try styling it to appear the way you want with ***CSS***.

Also, it appears you are formatting your ***HTML*** in the ***XHTML*** syntax. That is perfectly fine, however I recommend that you be consistent when closing tags. Two of your `<input />` element tags are not closed properly.

```
// This...
<input type="text" name="download" class="text required" id="Download_Input" size="3">

// Should be this...
<input type="text" name="download" class="text required" id="Download_Input" size="3" />

// And this...
<input type="text" name="time" class="text required" id="Time_Input" size="3">

// Should be this...
<input type="text" name="time" class="text required" id="Time_Input" size="3" />
```

Make sure you are consistent in your methods of markup. Inconsistencies such as this will result in an invalid markup.

Finally, I do not believe that you can have `<tr>` elements nested directly inside of a `<table>` element. I believe they have to be inside of a `<thead>`, `<tbody>` or `<tfoot>` element. Again, leaving out elements such as these results in invalid markup.

Comment: This is right. Using `prop()` instead of `attr()` when testing things like `checked` and `disabled` is the way to go.

Comment: When using this script, the text boxes do not become un-editable at all, even when the check boxes values are changed.

Comment: @user3010773 Sorry about that. I had a property incorrect. Try it again now with the code above. I've created a working example using your HTML and the code above in jsfiddle. Click the ***Fiddle*** link to try it out.

Comment: @War10ck I cannot get your code to work for whatever reason, you had done it in jsfiddle but when I apply it to my site, it does not work.

Comment: @user3010773 Hmm...It does work in the fiddle but not in your site? Is the jQuery library included? Also, where is this script placed? If it's placed in your `<head></head>` section, it needs to be wrapped using `$(document).ready(function () { ... });` as the resulting checkboxes will not have rendered when the jQuery goes to bind the events. I'll mockup a new fiddle showing this and post it here shortly...

Comment: @War10ck I have it placed at the end of my body that way the HTML loads first, and yes I do have the library included in the head.

Comment: @user3010773 [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/warlock5658/yjR48/1/) is an updated fiddle showing how you have to wrap the JavaScript in a document ready handler if placing it in the `<head></head>`.

Comment: @user3010773 Not sure what it could be. I'll dig a little deeper and get back to you on this. Do you see any errors in your browser console?

Comment: @War10ck I added tbody like you had said and used alex's code to get it to work, after I added the tbody, I used your code and it was opposite, but Alex's fixed the opposite problem, thank you so much